# C# While Loop Unintentional Reference

Tags: c#, arrays, reference

I am trying to use a while loop to determine when a process is completed, but in order to establish completion, I must compare the previous run with the current run, so I was setting the comparison array to the original...  this apparently is creating some sort of reference because when I change a value in the original "Distinct" array, the value also changes in the "InDistinct" comparison array.  How can I prevent/work around  this?  Otherwise my "while(Distinct!=InDistinct)" is useless.

```
int[,] Distinct = new int[100, 100]; //Establish Distinct Table
int[,] InDistinct= new int[100,100]; //Comparison Array 
//Initialize Distinct table to all 0's  (not shown)

while (InDistinct != Distinct)
        {
            InDistinct = Distinct;

            for (int j=0; j < DoIt.Sstates.Length; j++)
            {
                for (; k < DoIt.Sstates.Length; k++)
                {
                    if (DoIt.Sstates[k] == null)
                        break;
                    int w = 0;
                    for (w = 0; w < DoIt.alphabet.Length;w++)
                    {
                        if (DoIt.alphabet[w] == '\0')
                            break;
                        if (Distinct[j, k] == 0 && Distinct[jim.tLookup(DoIt, j, DoIt.alphabet[w]), jim.tLookup(DoIt, k, DoIt.alphabet[w])] == 1)
                            Distinct[j, k] = 1;
                        else if (Distinct[j, k] == 0 && Distinct[jim.tLookup(DoIt, k, DoIt.alphabet[w]), jim.tLookup(DoIt, j, DoIt.alphabet[w])] == 1)
                            Distinct[j, k] = 1;`
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this statement at the beginning of your while loop doing this?

```
while (InDistinct != Distinct)
    {
        InDistinct = Distinct;
```

The condition of your loop is checking if the InDistinct array value is not equal to the Distinct value but then makes the two equal by assigning the InDistinct value to that of the Distinct one immediately after.

Comment: Correct.  and then it runs an algorithm which I want to only change the value of the Distinct array, and then when it comes back to the top will check to see if the value of the altered Distinct array is the same as the InDistinct array, and if not, the loop continues.  If the algorithm has not changed the value of the Distinct array, it will be the same as the InDistinct array and the loop (and algorithm) will terminate. Otherwise, the InDistinct array will take on the new values of the Distinct array and the process will continue.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up initiating the InDistinct array above the While loop and copying the Distinct array to it via nested for loops:

```
int[,] InDistincta= new int[100,100];
while (InDistincta != Distinct)
{
    for (int a = 0; a < 100; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < 100; b++)
        {
            InDistincta[a, b] = Distinct[a, b];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Arrays are mechanisms that allow you to treat several items as a
>   single collection. The Microsoft® .NET Common Language Runtime (CLR)
>   supports single-dimensional arrays, multidimensional arrays, and
>   jagged arrays (arrays of arrays). All array types are implicitly
>   derived from System.Array, which itself is derived from System.Object.
>   This means that all arrays are always reference types which are
>   allocated on the managed heap, and your app's variable contains a
>   reference to the array and not the array itself.
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb985948.aspx

So you need to change

```
 InDistinct = Distinct;
```

just because after that line, the two names refers the same object.

try to copy target array into to the InDistinct object

```
targetArray = new string[sourceArray.Length];
sourceArray.CopyTo( targetArray, 0 );
```

for multi-dimensional arrays

```
Array.Copy(sourceArray,targetArray, sourceArray.Length);
```

Comment: it's a good idea, but CopyTo() apparently does not support multi-dimensional arrays:                                                                'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Only single dimensional arrays are supported for the requested action.

Comment: included multi-dimensional array solution to the answer. (you had already done that with loops, it's ok :) )